# How to kill uncompleted/ progressed thread?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I created a thread from main and detach it from main thread.
I want to kill this thread when it is in progress state.
I tried `std::terminate()` But it kill whole process . This thing i didn't want.
I want to kill that progress thread and start another thread in C++.

Please help me to solve this for `std::thread.`

Comment: Standard C++ library doesn't provide any way to terminate a running thread. You could design a mechanism to ask the thread to terminate gracefully (e.g. the thread could periodically check some atomic flag, and exit if this flag is raised).

Comment: Unilaterally killing threads is inherently problematic, because a killed thread has no ability to clean up any resources it was using (memory allocated, mutexes locked, files/sockets opened, etc), and the leakage of resources will cause problems for the rest of the process.  The only proper way to do it is to get the thread to voluntarily exit, as Igor suggested.

Comment: I think you got your answer already with those two comments. The problematic thing that @Jeremy talks about is called "thread cancellation", which should give you the keywords for further research.